# Adding a New Custom Page to phpBB

Tags: php, phpbb3

Please note that I have found this article [Add a New Custom Page to phpBB](https://www.phpbb.com/kb/article/add-a-new-custom-page-to-phpbb/) with which a new custom page can be created. I would like to ask: 1. how to remove "FAQ", "Register", "Login" and "Jump to" from that page? 2. how to add menu: About (a page with about info) and Videos (a page that will have links to videos). Totally there will be three menus, the one leading to Board, the other one leading to About page and the third one leading to the page with video links Thanks

Comment: .. Have you tried doing something alone?

Comment: I am on the road to build it up alone though I am not pretty aware of web development tools...I am not sure if it would be better to build a brand new template and embed within it the phpBB pages as well as the other two pages (about, videos) or to build it up within phpBB